# jQuery modify existing ajax request to clear cache

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui

I need to have no-cached ajax request, because I have problems, when it's cached. I can't modify original code, because it's from plugin and I need stable coded solution to modify it.

I have tried this code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   cache: false,
});
```

But unfortunatelly, it's having again cache.
Can anyone give me a tip about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a so called "cachebuster" to your url, for example a timestamp, in most cases this leads the server to deliver an uncached response as the url is not cached yet / has never been requested before.

```
url = url + "?cachebuster=" + Date.now()
```

if you read carefully the jquery ajax docs u can see the cache options `will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.` while in your case the response is probably cached by the server

update: You can add the "cachebuster" also with .ajaxSetup for all jquery ajax calls, sth. like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.data = $.extend(settings.data, { cachebuster: Date.now() });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you John, unfortunatelly not working fine into my case..

Comment: @VladimirKyatipov what specifically is not working?

Comment: I have jQuery ajax tab that's using WP Query to show posts and when user are on english version it's working, but when you go to german one - there is maybe a cache problem and user see a english posts. This problem is not happen, when you are logged in the website.